# Difference between using WHERE and AND with ON in SQL

Tags: sql, comparative-review

I have a Sql query

```
SELECT AccountMaster.AccountID, AccountMaster.AccountDesc, Settings.Description      
FROM AccountMaster

INNER JOIN Settings ON AccountMaster.AccountID = Settings.AcID
                    AND  Settings.CompanyID = @CompanyId
                    AND AccountMaster.CompanyID = @CompanyId
```

So I thought I could use like this

```
SELECT AccountMaster.AccountID, AccountMaster.AccountDesc, Settings.Description      
FROM AccountMaster

INNER JOIN Settings ON AccountMaster.AccountID = Settings.AcID
WHERE  Settings.CompanyID = @CompanyId 
       AND AccountMaster.CompanyID = @CompanyId
```

What is the difference and which one is better to use? or is the two queries run differently?

Comment: What engine do you use?

Comment: I find this question should be asked on [SO].

Comment: On SO it would be a duplicate of answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654338/27535 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063221/27535

Comment: @gbn well, then it means that this question is already answered and does not need to be asked again. OP should just read the answer. Why would you ask it here instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case with INNER JOIN there is no difference in result (OUTER JOIN would be different). Logically, they give the same result.

From a readability perspective, it's better to separate *JOIN* and *filter* conditions.

```
FROM 
  AccountMaster
  INNER JOIN 
  Settings ON 
      --This is a JOIN condition, with no outside restriction (date, id, etc)
      AccountMaster.AccountID = Settings.AcID
WHERE 
   --these are filters, independent of the join
   Settings.CompanyID = @CompanyId 
   AND
   AccountMaster.CompanyID = @CompanyId
```

As you get into reporting or data warehouse type queries, the number of JOINs and filters will increase massively. Keeping them separate helps readability.

Another point, when you read this out, the separation makes sense

> Give me rows from AccountMaster and Settings table where they match
>   on AccountID and AcID. Then filter to this CompanyId

Now, you might think "if I filter first it will be quicker".
Maybe it will, but this is the job of the query optimiser.

SQL is declarative: that is, you say what you want but not how to do it. The database engine (via the optimiser) will work out the best way to do it but honour your intention.

Logically, the order of processing is

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE/ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
12. OFFSET/FETCH
```

But the optimiser may filter first (WHERE), but will maintain the logical order.